# Meaning of "put in place a line of crossing stones"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> She ran from the passage, not minding that her footsteps were heard, not minding that the
> door to the yard banged loudly, that hearing it they would know she’d been
> listening. She ran into the woods, down to the stream, where only a few
> days ago she had helped her papa to **put in place a line of crossing stones.**

Does it mean: to put the stone that was for crossing over in their place?
Does "crossing stones" mean: the stones for walking on them?

Source: The Story of Lucy Gault by William Trevor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in both your guesses.

*Put in place* could be replaced by the simpler *lay* or *place*.

*Crossing stones* are usually called *stepping stones*, at least in the UK. I have never heard *crossing stones* (although the meaning is clear).